# A count in a loop

Tags: twig

Hello i would like do somthing like that:

```
<?php $count = 0; foreach($a as $v): $count++; ?>
  <?php if ($count%2 == 0): ?>
    ...
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

in twig:

```
{% for v in a %} 
  {% if ??? is even %}
    ...
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

but how can i have a variable evolving with loop ?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Apparently twig defines some [loop variables](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) inside the for-loop:

```
{% for v in a %}
    {% if loop.index0 is even %}
        ...
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: There is also such a thing as `{% if loop.index is divisible by(2) %}`, which would do the same. https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tests/divisibleby.html

Comment: The link in the answer has expired. Use this one instead: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable

Comment: @Charles hey thank you very much for the message, I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 24):

If you use it for styling you can do:

```
{% for v in a %} 
  <div class="link {{ cycle(['even', 'odd'], loop.index0) }}">
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. However, just a minor fix: It should be `cycle(['even', 'odd'], loop.index0)` because `loop.index0` is used. When you use `loop.index0` you are saying you have a "zeroth" row, and zero is an even number. So, with this fix your zeroth row is even, first row is odd, second row is even, etc.

Comment: Pretty neat solution, especially if you need something different than "even and odd", but for example "1st, 2nd and 3rd". Now, what about performance? Is maybe using `{% if loop.index0 is even %}` faster than cycling through a list of strings with `{{ cycle(['even', 'odd'], loop.index0) }}`? Would be interesting to know if there might be any reason to prefer one solution over the other or if it just doesn't matter in the end.